# Connection timeout while trying to SSH

Tags: ssh, server, connection, port

Hope I'm doing this right as this is my first StackOverflow question. I'm trying to SSH into a server, but running the ssh command results in a connection timeout (using the MobaXTerm client on Win10). I'm trying to connect on port 22, and have gone through Windows Firewall to make rules to open the port, but it's still not working. Any ideas as to why this is happening? I can provide relevant information as needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That error message means the server to which you are connecting does not reply to ssh connection on port 22. I think three possible reasons for that:

1. The server has not installed ssh
2. You are running ssh with different port
3. The machine has a firewall that doesnot allow you to connect